# I am trying to write inputed userdata into a txt file using php, but I can't get it it write. My html and php code is below

Tags: php, html

HTML: (Don't mind the gender selector, it's for r/badUIbattles) (Filename is first-page.html)

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Log in</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="data.php" method="post">
            <label for="email">Email Address:</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email"><br>
            <label for="password">Password</label><br>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="password"><br>
            <label for="gender">Pick your gender(Blue=male, pink=female, and anything in between is up to you!)</label><br>
            <input type="color" id="gender" name="gender" value="#000000"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

PHP: (Filename is data.php, txt file is userdata.txt)

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
              
        if(isset($_POST['email']))
        {
        $data=$_POST['email'];
    
        $fp = fopen('userdata.txt', 'a');
        fwrite($fp, $data);
        fclose($fp);
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am trying to store email and password in userdata.txt. Submit button just opens the code and doesn't run the script.

Comment: You mean you see the php code on the screen when you submit? That means it's not being executed. Make sure you're running this via a webserver which supports php

Comment: Your code does work for me. Do you have PHP running properly?

Comment: I was trying to run it locally. Thank you for confirming it works!

Comment: If you run it locally, ensure you've installed a webserver which can run PHP, such as Apache or IIS, with the right modules, and then execute your page in a browser via http, e.g. `http://localhost/data.php`.